# Ошибка "expression must have ariphmetic or ..." в С++

Tags: c++

```
for (int k = i + 1; k < 60; k++)
{
    float f = a[k, i] / a[i, i];
    for (int j = i + 1; j < 60; j++)
        a[k, j] = a[k, j] - a[i, j] * f;
    z[k] = z[k] - z[i] * f;
}
```

Вот код. Ошибку показывает на ячейках массивов a и z: float f =a[k,i]/a[i,i];
Вроде как, тип float можно делить на тип float. Так ведь? Оба массива такого типа. Что делать, чтобы избавиться от ошибки?

Comment: это не с++ синтаксис float f = a[k, i] / a[i, i] это не двумерный массив.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29933444/c-multi-dimensional-array-comma-index-address                                                                       Покажи весь код и скрин с ошибкой.

Comment: Господи. Какой же я тупой. Нет мне прощения. Спасибо за то, что ткнули лицом! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не с++ синтаксис **float f = a[k, i] / a[i, i]** и это не двумерный массив. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29933444/c-multi-dimensional-array-comma-index-address

Так будет работать если нет ошибок вне того участка кода что ты привел

```
for (int k = i + 1; k < 60; k++)
{
    float f = a[k][i] / a[i][i];
    for (int j = i + 1; j < 60; j++)
        a[k][j] = a[k][j] - a[i][j] * f;
    z[k] = z[k] - z[i] * f;
}
```